# Unable to see the lines in chart.js

Tags: django, chart.js

I am trying to make a django website which will display a chart that is updated every 1sec. I dont know why but except for the lines everything else is getting update [a snapshot of the graph with the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDYBC.png). the code below is my jquery in the html page

```js
{% block jquery %}
<script>
    var updateInterval = 20 //in ms
    var numberElements = 5
    var values = []

    //Globals
    var updateCount = 0
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data'
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var gchart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            label: [],
            datasets: [{

                label: 'Wholesale 24 K',
                data: [],
                fill: true,
                borderColor: 'rgb(245, 0, 0)',
                tension: 0.1,
                parsing: {
                    yAxisKey: 'b1'
                }
            }, {
                label: 'Retail 24 K',
                data: [],
                fill: true,
                borderColor: 'rgb(245, 225, 0)',
                tension: 0.1,
                parsing: {
                    yAxisKey: 's24K'
                }
            }]
        }, options: {
            interaction: {
                mode: 'index',
            }
        },
        
    })

    function addData(chart, label, data) {
        console.log(data)
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        });
        if (updateCount > numberElements) {
            gchart.data.labels.shift();
            gchart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
            gchart.data.datasets[1].data.shift();
        }
        else updateCount++;
        chart.update();
    }

    setInterval(ajaxcal, 1000)
    function ajaxcal() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function (data) {
                var lal = data.time
                addData(gchart, lal, data)
            },
            error: function (error_data) {
                console.log(error_data)
                console.log("Failed to fetch chart data from " + endpoint + "!")
            },

        })
    }
</script>
```

and this is my apiview

```
class ChartData(APIView):
authentication_classes = []
permission_classes = []

def get(self, request, format=None):

    g_dic = GetGoldRates()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


    tg = {
        'time': current_time,
        'b1': float(g_dic['karat24']),
        's24K': float(g_dic['fixkarat24']),

    }

    return Response(tg)
```

g_dic will usually get a dic like this `{'api_rate': '1796.03', 'karat24': '17.501', 'karat22': '16.031', 'karat21': '15.313', 'karat18': '13.126', 'fixkarat24': '17.950', 'fixkarat22': '17.050', 'fixkarat21': '16.300', 'fixkarat18': '14.000'}`

Could someone please help and point out my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling chart.js which custom key it needs to look for for the y axis but not for the x axis. So chart.js is looking for the `x` key in the object.

Changing your `parsing` config to include the `xAxisKey: 'time'` will fix your issue.

```html
<script>
    var updateInterval = 20 //in ms
    var numberElements = 5
    var values = []

    //Globals
    var updateCount = 0
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data'
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var gchart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            label: [],
            datasets: [{

                label: 'Wholesale 24 K',
                data: [],
                fill: true,
                borderColor: 'rgb(245, 0, 0)',
                tension: 0.1,
                parsing: {
                    yAxisKey: 'b1',
                    xAxisKey: 'time'
                }
            }, {
                label: 'Retail 24 K',
                data: [],
                fill: true,
                borderColor: 'rgb(245, 225, 0)',
                tension: 0.1,
                parsing: {
                    yAxisKey: 's24K',
                    xAxisKey: 'time'
                }
            }]
        }, options: {
            interaction: {
                mode: 'index',
            }
        },
        
    })

    function addData(chart, label, data) {
        console.log(data)
        chart.data.labels.push(label);
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        });
        if (updateCount > numberElements) {
            gchart.data.labels.shift();
            gchart.data.datasets[0].data.shift();
            gchart.data.datasets[1].data.shift();
        }
        else updateCount++;
        chart.update();
    }

    setInterval(ajaxcal, 1000)
    function ajaxcal() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function (data) {
                var lal = data.time
                addData(gchart, lal, data)
            },
            error: function (error_data) {
                console.log(error_data)
                console.log("Failed to fetch chart data from " + endpoint + "!")
            },

        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, i'm a bit confused, but wont the x axis come in the labels. I tried it and it works but why  mention x axis key when we are giving it to labels. Sorry i'm just curious

Comment: You are passing your entire object so chart.js expects a x and y to map the data to, so you need to tell which key is for the x axis. Or you will need to map your data so that you only provide an array with the correct values

Comment: thank you so much for the help, thank you

Comment: @Peter Johnson: Please mark this answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your problem (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409)